# Decrypt data in C# which is encrypted in java using RC4 encryption

Tags: java, c#, encryption

I have an encrypted file, which is encrypted in java using RC4 Encryption. Below is the code in java.

```
public class ata {
public static byte[] a(byte[] bArr, String str) {
    try {
        return ata.a(bArr, str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static byte[] a(byte[] bArr, byte[] bArr2) {
    try {
        Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
        instance.init(2, new SecretKeySpec(bArr2, "RC4"));
        return instance.update(bArr);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

I need to decrypt the file in C# so i need equivalent class of the java code in C#. Is anybody have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: RC4? That has been dead for a couple of decades, it is totally insecure. Also SO is not a translation service, add your best attempt to the question along with sample input/output and a description of any errors.

Comment: @zaph I got a java project from somewhere. That java application usage RC4 to encrypt the file, Now I want to decrypt that file in C#.